# jQuery toggle a class to another div, but only to that div?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have something like this, and just want to toggle a class

```
<div class="web">
/* wrapper 1 */
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1">
        <img src="/" />
        <p>sdas</p>
        <div class="buttons-box">
            <div class="button1"></div>
            <div class="button2"></div>  /* on click on this button */
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">  /* here add a class */
    </div>
</div>
    /* wrapper 2 */
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1">
        <img src="/" />
        <p>sdas</p>
        <div class="buttons-box">
            <div class="button1"></div>
            <div class="button2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2">  /* BUT NOT HERE */
    </div>
</div>
```

I think is clear for the ones how knows jQuery, Thank you !

Comment: which class.....what have you tried?

Comment: You want to  find the parent wrapper, then find the box2 element and add a class to it.

Comment: well i have tied something like this :                            $('.button2').on('click', function(e) {
       $('.box2').toggleClass("active"); 
   e.preventDefault();
     });                                                                                                                 but this adds class active to every box2 !

Answer (score 0):

If you want both of the wrappers to do the same thing but only for their wrapper you can do something like this.

```
$(".button2").on("click",function() {
    $(this).closest(".box2").toggleClass("Insert class here")
}
```

But if you want for the class to be toggled in only the first wrapper you're going to have to give the button an ID. Like this

```
<div class="button2" id="BtnID"></div> 

$("#BtnID").on("click",function() {
    $(this).closest(".box2").toggleClass("Insert class here")
}
```